# How do I know what each pin represents in a Spice model of an op-amp in OrCAD?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, pins, pspice, orcad

I have imported a Spice model of an op-amp into OrCAD, but the part symbol is different from what I am used to, and I don't know what pins 4, 5, 8, and 11 represent here.

Link to spice model I used: [https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~strouce/analogbc/opamp2.htm](https://www.eng.auburn.edu/%7Estrouce/analogbc/opamp2.htm)

Here is the symbol I am getting:

[image]

Edit: Found out what each pin represents. I made a voltage follower circuit, but no matter the input supply my output voltage is stuck at -13.53V

Voltage follower circuit I used:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like the subcircuit intentionally uses SPICE2 syntax where ["Nodes must be nonnegative integers.."](http://bear.ces.cwru.edu/eecs_cad/man_spice2_sec1.html).  This of course makes it confusing because you can't use names for the pins.  Still poor form because the author can include comments (lines starting with asterisks) to give a legend to the user detailing the pinout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provide shows `.subckt` code which (mostly) matches the accompanying image of the opamp's internal schematic.  I'll duplicate both for clarity and completeness below:

```
*operational ampplifier 2(Leap frog opamp)

.Subckt opamp 4 5 8 1 11
.MODEL mosn NMOS
+ vto=1 kp=17u gamma=1.3 lambda=0.01 phi=0.7
+pb=0.8 mj=0.5 mjsw=.3 cgso=350p cgdo=350p cgbo=200p
+cj=300u cjsw=500p ld=0.8u tox=80n
.MODEL mosp PMOS
+ vto=-1 kp=8u gamma=.6 lambda=0.02 phi=0.6
+pb=0.5 mj=0.5 mjsw=.25 cgso=350p cgdo=350p cgbo=200p
+cj=150u cjsw=400p ld=0.8u tox=80n
R1a 6 66 1
R1b 66 3 100meg
m1 66 4 3 3 mosp w=20u l=10u
R2a 7 77 1
R2b 77 3 100meg
m2 77 5 3 3 mosp w=20u l=10u
R3a 6 67 1
R3b 67 11 100meg
m3 67 6 11 11 mosn w=36u l=10u
R4a 7 78 1
R4b 78 11 100meg
m4 78 6 11 11 mosn w=36u l=10u
R5a 3 33 1
R5b 33 1 100meg
m5 33 2a 1 1 mosp w=30u l=10u
R6a 8 88 1
R6b 88 11 100meg
m6 88 7 11 11 mosn w=100u l=10u
R7a 8 89 1
R7b 89 1 100meg
m7 89 2 1 1 mosp w=42u l=10u
R8a 2 22 1
R8b 22 11 100meg
m8 22 6 11 11 mosn w=60u l=10u
R9a 2 23 1
R9b 23 1 100meg
m9 23 2 1 1 mosp w=30u l=10u
Rc 7 76 1
cc 76 8 6p
Rs 76 8 100meg
vbias 2a 0 .1
.ends
```

[image]

Our goal is to try and map the node numbers listed on the `.subckt` line to the actual pins labeled on the schematic image.

`.subckt opamp 4 5 8 1 11`

---

The first clue I see is there is only one capacitor, and one of its sides is connected to Vout in the image.  I can easily find the capacitor in the `.subckt` code because it's the only line that starts with the letter "C":

`cc 76 8 6p`

Therefore, pin 8 is Vout.

---

Next, the image shows M7 as a PMOS transistor with its source connected to Vdd.  MOSFET transistors in SPICE follow the following syntax and pin ordering:

`Mxxx <drain> <gate> <source> <body> <modelname> [W=<width>] [L=<length>]`

So for M7 we have:

`m7 89 2 1 1 mosp w=42u l=10u`

and therefore, pin 1 is Vdd.

---

We can do the same with NMOS transistor M6 and Vss:

`m6 88 7 11 11 mosn w=100u l=10u`

which means pin 11 is Vss.

---

The noninverting (+) input is connected to the gate of M2:

`m2 77 5 3 3 mosp w=20u l=10u`

So following the syntax definition above, pin 5 is the noninverting input.

---

Lastly, we do the same with the inverting (-) input and M1:

`m1 66 4 3 3 mosp w=20u l=10u`

which means pin 4 is the inverting input.

---

Summarizing, we have the following:

```
4  = inverting (-) input
5  = noninverting (+) input
8  = Vout
1  = Vdd
11 = Vss
```

Shown below is a DC operating point example of a "gain of 2" noninverting amplifier.  One thing to note about this opamp model is that it only functions well enough in DC with high valued resistors.  Reduce the gain/feedback resistors by a factor of 10 or 100 to see what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The model you linked has this line: -

```
.Subckt opamp 4 5 8 1 11
```

And, if I look at similar op-amp models that I use, the pin order in my models are this: -

```
+Vin -Vin +Vsup -Vsup Output
```

So, it's a fair bet that if you connected up your model as an non-inverting voltage follower, you should get a response that looks like one. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I did made a non-inverting voltage follower, connecting the output to -Vin, applying a DC source at +Vin and used +15/-15 as Vsup. My output is stuck at -14.11V no matter the input supply.

Comment: Maybe you should add that schematic into your question within a clear edited section so that your original question is intact @AnshulMahawar